# Google drive API Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch on Android but not Unity Editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-drive-api

Me and my teammates are implementing an android application that takes and sends files to the user's google drive.

We implemented this app using Unity 2020.3.15. We used https://github.com/Elringus/UnityGoogleDrive library. We have followed the setup and additional setup steps for iOS and Android.

The app works perfectly when run in the unity editor (it connects to google drive and exchanges files). However the following error appears when running on android:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

[error 400 redirect_uri_mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvpCx.jpg)

We have tried changing the Bundle ID. We also tried  changing the redirect uri from  http://localhost to https://localhost as said in this post: [Google drive API Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001964/google-drive-api-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-with-unity). However we still get this error.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Could be this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710262/google-drive-redirect-uri-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710262/google-drive-redirect-uri-mismatch)

Comment: Do you have a current app that uses targets Android 13?